# Is there a better way to marshal sql rows?

Tags: mysql, json, go

I have the following struct:

```
type MyTable struct{
  DBColA []byte `db:"cola" json:"-"`
  ColA string `json:"cola"`
  DBColB []byte `db:"colb" json:"-"`
  ColB string `json:"colb"`
}
```

I map to []byte [to better handle null values in my sql][1]

When I grab the rows I need to output it as json. In order to do that I convert []byte to string:

```
var rows []*MyTable
if _, err := Session.Select(&rows, sql, args...); err != nil {
    log.Println(err)
}
for _, row := range rows{
   row.ColA = string(row.DBColA)
   row.ColB = string(row.DBColB)
}
w.Header().Set("Content-Type", "application/json")
if err := json.NewEncoder(w).Encode(rows); err != nil {
  http.Error(w, err.Error(), http.StatusInternalServerError)
}
```

It seems very inefficient to have DBColA and ColA in my struct and then converting DBColA to a string....I have a lot of columns. Is there a better way?

```
  [1]: https://github.com/go-sql-driver/mysql/wiki/Examples
```

Comment: You say that it seems very inefficient.  Is it, in fact, actally inefficient in a way that negatively impacts the application?

Comment: @RobertHarvey it negatively impacts my productivity.

Comment: @RobertHarvey: reworded the question...it isn't an application thing is a programmer's productivity thing

Comment: There are almost certainly better ways to do this.   I would see if Go has ORM and data mapping libraries.

Comment: Using Gorp. I map to byte slice to better handle the null values. The issue is then finding a better way to convert the byte slice values to json

Comment: Why aren't you using `NullString`? This is no different to nullable constructs in other languages.

Comment: @SimonWhitehead: Because then you'd have to do something far more uglier than what I have to marshall a NullString type to json: http://dennissuratna.com/marshalling-nullable-string-db-value-to-json-in-go/....unless I am missing an easier way ;)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Have you tried [gosqljson](https://github.com/elgs/gosqljson) in https://github.com/elgs/gosqljson ?

See example:

```golang

```
package main

import (
    "database/sql"
    "fmt"
    "github.com/elgs/gosqljson"
    _ "github.com/go-sql-driver/mysql"
)

func main() {
    ds := "username:password@tcp(host:3306)/db"
    db, err := sql.Open("mysql", ds)
    defer db.Close()

    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("sql.Open:", err)
    }

    theCase := "lower" // "lower" default, "upper", camel

    a, _ := gosqljson.QueryDbToArrayJson(db, theCase, "SELECT ID,NAME FROM t LIMIT ?,?", 0, 3)
    fmt.Println(a)
    // [["id","name"],["0","Alicia"],["1","Brian"],["2","Chloe"]]

    m, _ := gosqljson.QueryDbToMapJson(db, theCase, "SELECT ID,NAME FROM t LIMIT ?,?", 0, 3)
    fmt.Println(m)
    // [{"id":"0","name":"Alicia"},{"id":"1","name":"Brian"},{"id":"2","name":"Chloe"}]

}
```

````

Comment: I'm the author of this library. Now I have made some update. `theCase` can be original, `lower`, `upper` and `camel`. The returned array now separated the headers and data to make the data processing easier. Thanks @Nery Jr for the recommendation. I wish `gosqljson` is helpful to your projects. Here is a link you might find helpful: http://srcode.org/2014/08/19/sql-to-json-in-golang/